# SharedPreferences won't be saved

Tags: java, android

I'm im trying to save the String lolzor, but I can't seem to make it reappear once the app has been destroyed and restarted,  I have tried multiple solutions but non of them seems to work for me  can anyone help?

thanks in advance

Thanks to aegean i found the solution. The problem was neither saving or getteing the information but the fact that once i retreived the saved information i did'nt use it.

The code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String GEMFFS = "dk.SimonPedersen.GEMFFS";



SharedPreferences ada;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Button btnGem;
ToggleButton tbKon;
EditText etVaegt;
Double sex, vaegt, KT;
String lols, lolzor, KTO;
TextView haha;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ada = getSharedPreferences(GEMFFS, 0);

    haha=(TextView)findViewById (R.id.haha);
    btnGem = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnGem);
    tbKon = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.tbKon);
    etVaegt = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etVaegt);



    tbKon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                sex=0.7d;
            } else {
                sex=0.6d;
            }
           Log.d("Konskonstant", "sex" + sex);
        }
    });



    btnGem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            lols=etVaegt.getText().toString();
            vaegt=Double.parseDouble(lols);
            KT = sex*vaegt;
            lolzor=KT.toString();
            haha.setText("KT " + KT);
        }

});

}
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GEMFFS, 0);
    String KT = settings.getString("KT", null);
}
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GEMFFS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("KT", lolzor);
    editor.commit();
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GEMFFS, 0);
    String KT = settings.getString("KT", null);
}
```

To this:

```
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GEMFFS, 0);
    KTO = settings.getString("KT", null);
    KT = Double.valueOf(KTO);

}
```

Also set this value where you want to(to any `TextView`)

**NOTE:** You don't have any problem with saving and getting value. Only problem is you are not using it when you get it.